# shared element return wrong position when turn on "Dont keep activities" option in Setting

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

In my app, I used shared element. It works fine, but if I turn on the option "Don't keep activities", the shared element items don't know the way to return back, so the position go wrong.

I see in google play store app, they simply don't use the animation when return when I turn on "Don't keep activities". How can I make the behavior like them?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this video from Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L4fLrWDvAU&feature=youtu.be), and [sample app on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-unsplash)

[DetailSharedElementEnterCallback](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-unsplash/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/unsplash/ui/DetailSharedElementEnterCallback.java) contains remapping